# Postgres join on jsonb array that contains Key:value pair in another jsonb array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, join

This SQL works but instead of joining on just the first value in the array in encounter.document -> account, I need to search all values in the array.

```
SELECT encounter.* FROM encounter JOIN account
ON (account.document -> 'identifier') @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('value', encounter.document #> '{account, 0, identifier, value}', 'system', encounter.document #> '{account, 0, identifier, system}')
WHERE account.foo = 'bar'
```

Example Encounter:

```
encounter.document = {"account": [{"system": "foo", "value": "bar"}, {"system": "two-foo", "value": "two-bar"}]}
```

Example Account:

```
account.foo = bar
account.document = {"identifier": [{"system": "foo", "value": "bar"}, {"system": "blah", "value": "blah"}]}
```

Given the above records, I would expect to get the encounter record back because the "account" array in the encounter record contains and object that is in the "identifier" array of an account record and that account record has a foo value = bar.

Give me all the encounter records where the "account" array contains and item that is also contained in the "identifier" array on an account record and where that account record has foo = bar - Would be another way to put it.

It seems I'm able to do it if I add several ORs to the on clause incremnting the index of the array like:

```
ON ((account.document -> 'identifier') @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('value', encounter.document #> '{account, 0, identifier, value}', 'system', encounter.document #> '{account, 0, identifier, system}')
OR(account.document -> 'identifier') @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('value', encounter.document #> '{account, 1, identifier, value}', 'system', encounter.document #> '{account, 1, identifier, system}'))
```

But that feels very dirty.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Updated with more info @eshirvana

Answer (score 0):

one way to make it more generic and bullet-proof is :

```
select a.*
from(
        select *
        from encounter e
        cross join jsonb_to_recordset(jsonb_extract_path(e.document, 'account')) as x (value varchar(100), system varchar(100))
    ) a
    join (
        select *
        from account a
        cross join jsonb_to_recordset(jsonb_extract_path(a.document, 'identifier')) as y (value varchar(100), system varchar(100))
    ) b on a.value = b.value
    and a.system = b.system
    and a.value = 'foo'
    and a.system = 'bar'
```